# getting size of child object inside parent function

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know the size of the derived class object inside parent function. The parent function in my case is virtual and hence I cannot use sizeof(child class name) and I have to decide dynamically based on the object passed. Below is the code snippet. I used sizeof(*this) inside PrintBalance() of parent class and that will not work. I need something similar to that. I am explicitly calling parent class function from overridden child class.

```
class Account
{
protected:
    int var1;
    int var2;
    double m_balance;

    public:

    Account( double d )
    {

        m_balance = d;
    }

    virtual double GetBalance()
    {
        return m_balance;
    }
    virtual void PrintBalance()
    {
        cout<<"size in Parent= "<< sizeof(*this)<<endl;
    }
private:

};

class CurrentAccount : public Account
{
    int var3;
    int var4;
public:
    CurrentAccount(double d) : Account(d) {}

    void PrintBalance()
    {
        Account::PrintBalance();
        cout<<"size in Derived = "<< sizeof(*this)<<endl;
        cout << "Current account balance: " << GetBalance() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CurrentAccount cAcc(1000);
    CurrentAccount *pCurrent = &cAcc ;
    pCurrent->PrintBalance();
    pCurrent->GetBalance();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a serious design flaw for me. Why do you actually need to know the size?

Comment: Yes, I also thought it could be a design issue . But thought of asking this forum for alternatives if any before changing my design.

Comment: Again: Why do you believe you need to know the size at that point?

Comment: I thought of going for common function for printing and that is why I put printing function in parent class. May be I have to go for separate class for printing and make it friend I guess (I am Just understanding C++ concepts and cannot immediately decide).

Comment: Make `virtual void PrintBalance();` a pure virtual function in your base class like that: `virtual void PrintBalance() = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a virtual method in the base class and override it in all derived classes returning the size of the class/type.

```
class Account
{
public:
    //....
    virtual size_t GetSizeOf() const
    {
        return sizeof(*this);
    }
    //....
    virtual void PrintBalance()
    {
        std::cout << "size in Parent= " << this->GetSizeOf() << std::endl;
    }
    //...
};

class CurrentAccount : public Account
{
public:
    //...
    size_t GetSizeOf() const override
    {
        return sizeof(*this);
    }
    //...
    void PrintBalance() override
    {
        Account::PrintBalance();
        std::cout << "size in Derived = " << this->GetSizeOf() << std::endl;
        // ...
    }
};
```

So it should print the same size from both methods - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37177e4e6e899090.

---

**UPDATE**

To print the members of all derived classes from the base you need a virtual method that allows the derived to extend the base.

**EXAMPLE 1:** Print derived class's members using override:

```
class Account
{
protected:
    //....
    virtual void DoPrint() const
    {
        std::cout << "print Account's members" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    //....
    void PrintBalance()
    {
        //std::cout << "size in Parent= " << this->GetSizeOf() << std::endl;
        DoPrint();
    }
};

class CurrentAccount : public Account
{
protected:
    //...
    void DoPrint() const override
    {
        Account::DoPrint();
        std::cout << "print CurrentAccount's members" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You could also change the base to use a dictionary or even a list of print callbacks.

**Example 2:** Print derived class's members without override: (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56402cff02a922d2):

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// not using namespace std;

class Account
{
protected:
    int var1 = 1;
    int var2 = 2;
    double m_balance = 3.0;
public:
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> printers;  // Could be made static and pass `this` and as parameter

    Account()
    {
        printers.emplace_back([this]() {
            std::cout << "var1= "<< var1 << "\n"
                      << "var2= "<< var2 << "\n"
                      << "m_balance= "<< m_balance << std::endl;
        });
    }
    //....
    void PrintBalance()
    {
        for ( const auto& p : printers )
        {
            p();   
        }
    }
    //...
};

class CurrentAccount : public Account
{
protected:
    int var3 = 4;
    int var4 = 5;
public:
    CurrentAccount(): Account() {
        printers.emplace_back([this]() {
            std::cout << "var3= "<< var3 << "\n"
                      << "var4= "<< var4 << std::endl;
        });
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. In the same way, how can I get reference to child class object so that I can print any child object data from parent class (using Override)? Since auto type is not allowed in C++11, is this possible unless I go for C++14?

Comment: You cannot know what data your derived classes (will) have. So you'll need additional virtual method that each child must override and print its own members. An option could be to use a dictionary with variants in the base class and they could add their fields to it. This is the only way to get the printing only in the parent working without doing something in the derived.